# File is locked, not letting me copy it

Tags: c#, file-io, file-copying

**I have a file that I want to backup, I don't have anything "touching" the file that I "know" of.  But I get the message:**

```
"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Cadence\SPB_Data\pcbenv\allegro.ilinit' because it is being used by another process
```

**Source Code:**

```
string fileName = @"C:\Cadence\SPB_Data\pcbenv\allegro.ilinit";
string sourcePath = @"C:\Cadence\SPB_Data\pcbenv";
string targetPath = @"C:\Cadence\SPB_Data\pcbenv\backup";

// Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths. 
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

// To copy a folder's contents to a new location: 
// Create a new target folder, if necessary. 
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
}

// To copy a file to another location and  
// overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

**So as soon as the program hits this line "  System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);"  I get the error.  Any way to "force" a copy ?**

Comment: The file is for sure being held hostage by "something"

Comment: I did have it open in notepad++, but I closed it and triple checked everywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other process has marked the file as "read locked" then you are not going to be able to copy the file.

Your best bet is to figure out what process is locking the file using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: I can read in the file, so I suppose that reading it in and then writing it back out would work...

Comment: Yes, if you can read it you should be able to do that.  Here is an example that someone else posted for that scenario:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6167163/73446

Answer (score 1):

Do you create this file/ write into this file in the application before you try to copy it? If you did create/write into it then you may have forgotten to close it after that.

Comment: Yes I do,  looking into that now.

Comment: I even created a new file manually and nothing should have it open has to be that code from microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your source and destination for the copy operation are the same. You are using `Path.Combine` incorrectly. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

> If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

Since you have a root in `path2` (the second parameter) both `sourceFile` and `destFile` are the value of `fileName`.

You probably want to declare `string fileName = "allegro.ilinit"` instead of what you have.

Obviously, the exception message is somewhat misleading.