# can't get access to the file C#

Tags: c#, save, ioexception

I am writing a program in C# which has to:
* make the user choose a file from a 'browse-screen' for example "C:/temp/DirectoryExample/FileExample.xxx"
* save the chosen file as the name of the directory it was chosen from (in this case DirectoryExample.xxx) in a location that is pre-set by the program.

i have tried using these options to accomplish this:

```
if (sfdGekozenBestand.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    tbGekozenBestand.Text = sfdGekozenBestand.FileName;
    tbVeranderNaamIn.Text = f_sNieuweNaam;
    File.Copy(tbVeranderNaamIn.Text, f_sNieuweNaam, true);
}
```

**Or**

```
if (sfdGekozenBestand.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    tbGekozenBestand.Text = sfdGekozenBestand.FileName;
    tbVeranderNaamIn.Text = f_sNieuweNaam;
    f_srStreamReader = new StreamReader(tbGekozenBestand.Text);
    f_swStreamwriter = new StreamWriter(f_sNieuweNaam);
}
```

Here is the thing, when i debug it in Visual studio 2010.
I click the save button in the SaveFileDialog, it asks me if want to overwrite the currently existing file, I click Yes.
then it crashes and gives me this:

> IOExeption was unhandled.
>
> Can't get access to the file C:/temp/DirectoryExample.xxx because it
>   is in use by another proces

the troubleshooting tips are worthless, and my google-using skills are coming in short.

Any help would be appriciated.

**[EDIT]**

Fixed with [How to copy a file while it is being used by other process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167136/how-to-copy-a-file-while-it-is-being-used-by-other-process)

Comment: Is the file at `C:/temp/DirectoryExample.xxx` opened by another tool, like Notepad or Visual Studio itself?

Comment: Do you open the file before it? if yes, verify you perfrom Close()

Comment: @KarlAnderson well, I am not sure, i checked with an process explorer and it didn't show up in the list. i don't put the file in a stream or anything. when i select it in the 'Browse' screen Visual Studio might reserve it for some reason. but i can't tell

Comment: Even though it says "another process", what it really means is "it's already open". So it could be your own program that has it open.