# How to modify sqlite db file located in application folder

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am using sqlite in desktop application. Once application is installed, a database file is created in installation folder (application folder in program files). I would like to modify the sqlite file, but can't.

When i try to modify, it shows read-only error in sqlite file.

I also tried to give permission to that folder, but it does not work.

Comment: What happens if you try and use something like SQLite Administrator to open the db? http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

Comment: The thread linked to this question has absolutely nothing to do with the person's original question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a copy of the .sqlite file and modify this one:

[How to copy a file while it is being used by other process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167136/how-to-copy-a-file-while-it-is-being-used-by-other-process)

Obviously you won't be able to write to the very same database file that your application has locked. And I cannot see any reason why you want to do this when the application is currently running. This would potentially lead to data inconsistency issues.