# Locked directory and getting FileNotFoundException during File.Copy

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, filenotfoundexception

I´m trying to copy a shared file to local copy:

```
File.Copy("\\sharedmachine\directory\file.exe", "\\localmachine\directory\file.exe", true);
```

The source file exists but if another user/machine is opened directory in the "Windows Explorer" for example, this operation lock and during the copy i´m getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

There are some way to copy file even if someone open the directory in another machine?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167163/1454084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opening the file as read-only and then writing it to the destination, so that apps accessing the file is not blocked.

```
using (var from = File.Open("sourcePath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var to = File.OpenWrite("destPath"))
    {
        from.CopyTo(to);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe provide some details as to why you believe your code is correct, or what yours solves that the OP's does not.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne don't you think code is self explanatory?

Comment: To me, but maybe not to the OP that has 3 points.  Adding a one-line comment to say that you are opening the file as read-only and then writing it to the destination, so that apps accessing the file is not blocked  - would be helpful for others to understand.  It is your answer and you should provide the best answer you can to move the whole community forward with you.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne agree. Added your explanation :)