# How to copy a file to another folder while a process is using it

Tags: c#, file, process, copy, copy-paste

How do I copy any file that is being used to another process to a specified folder, without affecting / corrupting what that process is doing?

Context: I'm making a program that will copy a project folder each X minutes to 2 cloud servers and 1 hard-drive, while that project is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the post below:

> The important part is the FileShare.ReadWrite when opening the
>   FileStream

.

[How to copy a file while it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167136/how-to-copy-a-file-while-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

In short, make sure that you specify the correct access parameters while opening the file.