# How to enumerate all processes consuming a specific file

Tags: c#, windows, handle

Using MS Windows, deleting a file sometimes does not work since "**file xyz.abc is used by another process**" message appears. Sometimes the message tells me which process is holding the handle, mostly it does not.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to get all PIDs/Handles that are "locking" this file I want to delete.

I already found a [WinAPI function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217(VS.85).aspx) that tells me the process name of a handle. What I need is a function, that tells me the PIDs/Handles assigned to a file.

It would be glad if you could provide some code (in C/C++ or any .NET language)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can but stack overflow doesnt give you code.. it helps you fix your code.  Do a google - thats where I got mine from - such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899864/what-process-locks-a-file/3900019

Comment: The [Restart Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc948910.aspx) provides this functionality. See [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283) for complete code sample.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for your advise, i read to quickly the orinigal post and understood the threadstarter than he already gets the process-name which is currently locking given file. Now i see that i was wrong.