# C# Get all executables from directory structure, then kill if running

Tags: c#

I'm trying to:

1) get a list of all executables in a directory and all subdirectories.

2) if any of those executables is running, kill the process.

What I have so far:

```
String[] exes =
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Temp", "*.EXE", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Select(fileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName))
.ToArray();

{
    exes.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

So this shows me a list of the executables. How do I use this list to kill the processes, if they are running?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648410/how-can-i-list-all-processes-running-in-windows

Comment: Should you not turn this around and instead enumerate all processes and kill them if (the primary/any) module's path is within that directory structure? Is there a reason to want/not expect that there could be an exe running that has loaded a DLL from that directory but that process should be exempted from killing?

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899864/what-process-locks-a-file as a basis to rewrite fuser for windows.. allows you to itterate processes for a given file, with some tweeking you could change it to work with a number of files you got from your file list

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm just learning C#, so forgive my ignorance. Why would that be better, and how would that look, code-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with this:

```
                    try
                {
                    //Find exes in dir and subdirs
                    String[] exes =
                    Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Temp", "*.EXE", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(fileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName))
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .ToArray();

                    // kill the process if it is in the list 
                    var runningProceses = Process.GetProcesses();
                    for (int i = 0; i < runningProceses.Length; i++)
                    {

                     if (exes.Contains(runningProceses[i].ProcessName))
                     {
                      runningProceses[i].Kill(); 
                     }

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```