# PowerShell to get all the processes which are using(i.g. write/read to the file, etc) a given file name

Tags: windows, powershell

> Problem:

Hi, I am trying to find all the processes which are using(reading or writing) a particular file using Powershell only.

I have tried using Get-Process with where-Object filter but it is not working.
I have very less experience in Windows hence finding it difficult to understand where to look and how to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are you [trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Finding out process that holds a file lock is easily done with, say, Sysinternals' Handle.exe.

Comment: I want to write my own function to check if the file is read or write by the process (not just the lock). And I want to do it in Powershell only.
@vonPryz

Comment: If you cannot use 3rd party tools, then P/Invoke is needed to call Win32 API. Pick a [C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899864) and work from that.

Comment: @vonPryz Oh! does that mean that it is not possible to create a simple function in PowerShell to check the processes which have the file open with them?

Comment: As far as I know, handles are not exposed to managed code. Thus one needs to either call Win32 API via P/Invoke or use 3rd party tools and parse the output.

Answer (score 1):

Information in this blog post should be able to help out -
http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/3744/friday-fun-find-file-locking-process-with-powershell/

The Sysinternals suite has a tool called 'Handle.exe' which if you pass it a file, will let you know what process has a handle to that file (if one exists).

Comment: Site/link seems dead.

Comment: works for me. should probably update my answer though to not use it